# Syntax Error : Unexpected identifier NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I am trying to create a http server using this code .While I try to run it 
error comes ( Syntax Error : Unexpected identifier) .
Now I haven't found any error there.

```
var http = require('http');

//Lets define a port we want to listen to
const PORT=8080; 

//We need a function which handles requests and send response
function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.end('It Works!! Path Hit: ' + request.url);
}

//Create a server
var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);

//Lets start our server
server.listen(PORT, function(){
    //Callback triggered when server is successfully listening. Hurray!
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:%s", PORT);
});
```

Comment: Any hint where the error occurs?

Comment: thank you for your interest I had solved the issue .

Answer (score 0):

Most people run that command outside of the node session itself.

```
> Thoms-MacBook-Pro:desktop thomvaladez$ node example.js
```

If you're already in the node session as you've done then--as t3dodson has suggested--you do a require at that point. Only you need to prepend that with a "./" so that it will find your file.

```
> Thoms-MacBook-Pro:desktop thomvaladez$ node
> require ('./example.js')
> Hello World!
```

I'm guessing that "node" then in your version is the "Unexpected identifier".